# Display the result based on the comma seperated value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have comma seperated value in my table, tbl_request as follows:

```
request_id   name1  price
4            12,14  99.23
```

From this table I need to find the data from another table based on the value name1 i.e. 12, 14. I have tried following code

```
SELECT
    r.price,
    (
        SELECT
            GROUP_CONCAT(pd.product_name)
        FROM
            tbl_products AS pd
        WHERE
            (
                pd.product_id IN(GROUP_CONCAT(r.name1))
            )
    ) as xyz
FROM
    tbl_request AS r
WHERE
    r.request_id = 4
```

I need to get the product name of the id in name1 in comma seperated value. But with above code I can get only one value. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Put your effort into fixing your data structure and not into writing queries to make it work.

Comment: You have wrong structure in db, look at normal forms and correct the structure before it's too late.

Comment: @Robert I was asked to fix the issue in other teams project. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a broken data structure.  Here are reasons why it is bad:

- It is bad to store numbers as strings.
- A column in a SQL database should have one value.
- SQL has poor string-manipulation support.
- Foreign key relationships should be properly defined (and you cannot do that with a list).
- String manipulations preclude the use of indexes.

Fix your data and put the values into a proper *junction* table, with the right types and foreign key relationships.

Sometimes, we are stuck with other people's really bad, bad, bad, bad, bad design decisions.  MySQL offers `find_in_set()` which can help with this purpose:

```
SELECT r.price, GROUP_CONCAT(pd.product_name) as xyz
FROM tbl_request r LEFT JOIN
     tbl_products p
     ON find_in_set(p.product_id, r.name1) > 0
WHERE r.request_id = 4
GROUP BY r.price;
```

Comment: Thank You for you advice. I will keep it in my mind. But for now I have to go with find_in_set

Answer (score 3):

You may use `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('12', name1) > 0;     -- a non-zero value means a match
```

The above call to `FIND_IN_SET` would search the `name1` column, which consists of CSV strings, for the value `12` appearing as any value.

Note that it is generally bad practice to store CSV data in your database tables, because it represents unnormalized data, and you can expect bad performance.